# Attaching methods to javascript functions then passing them to variables

Tags: javascript, variables

I have a javascript function (using NodeJS but not particularly relevant here) like this:

```
var method = {};
method.create = function(){
  console.log('Method was created')
}

method.create.function1 = function(){
  console.log("This is method 2")
}

method.create.series = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
```

If I call `method.create.function1()` it correctly runs that function and console logs: `This is method 2`.

If I call `method.create.series[0]`, I am returned: `"one"`

However, if I call:

```
 var app = method.create();
 app.function1() // returns undefined
```

I've tried:

```
var method = {};
method.create = function(){
    console.log('Method was created')

    this.function1 = function(){
      console.log("This is method 2")
    }

    this.series = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
}
```

but this doesn't work at all. Anything I can do to be able to pass these methods along to a new variable?

Comment: Why would that work? `method.create()` returns `undefined`.

Comment: FWIW, `method` is a very misleading thing to call a variable that refers to an object rather than a function. It's also *fairly* unusual to assign functions as properties on function objects, although it can certainly be useful in some cases (KnockoutJS does it with observables, for instance, and of course all normal JavaScript functions have methods on them like `call`, `apply`, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a big difference between the expressions `method.create` and `method.create()`. The first results in a reference to the function object; the second *calls* the function and results in its return value. Since your `create` function doesn't return anything, the result of calling it is the value `undefined.

If you want to have a reference to `method.create` in `app` and then use it, you use the first expression (*without* `()`):

```
var app = method.create;
app.function1(); // Works
```